# Sitecore headless with React frontend - JSS or SC 10?

Tags: react, jss

We would like to gradually migrate our current Sitecore 9.2 MVC site to a headless architecture. For the frontend we would like to use React.

Considering that Sitecore 10.1 just released with additional headless support, would that headless support cater to React.js for the frontend or does it lean more towards .NET core?

Comment: You need to take this to a discussion forum; either Slack or the Community Forums

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your requirements, what you'd like to achieve and in what timeframe. You should consider that even if 10.1 just released, it will take some time until the project you want to migrate to will be released.

If you plan on having all the sitecore capabilities (like personalization) in your React app you should use the first two options, as you need sitecore once you deploy your app and use connected mode. It depends a lot also on how you plan to build the React app and how you'd use JSS, please take a look at the documentation https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/fundamentals/application-modes.

I would suggest to also look into
https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/nextjs/getting-started-nextjs/why-nextjs for building the app.